# How to get same output when we are using request.get(url) and driver.get(url)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
url = 'https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/warning/#lang=en'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
print(soup)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(
ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Output for both above code are different

when I try to print output using request.get(url) so I am getting a different output from driver.get(url)

Is there any way I can get same output as driver.get(url) using requests library in python

Comment: may be you can explain why do you want to get same outputs there? so we can think of other possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

`driver.get()` loads a web page in the current browser session.
This method does not return any value. So it will always be `None`.

`requests.get()` sends a GET request and returns `requests.Response` class.

Comment: Hi,
The issue is I am trying to webscrap html page using url which is given in code but when I try using request and BeautifulSoup I am getting a different ouput as which I got from using webdriver and BeautifulSoup

So I want to know is there any way I can get same output using requests and BeautifulSoup
or is there any other library which can give me same output as webdriver code shown above

Comment: AFAIK driver.page_source sends request to chrome webdriver and it just returns source code of currently opened page including any changes that may have happened during js scripts execution and user interactions. Meanwhile requests.get sends requests directly to url provided and server returns some html code stored for this endpoint. So if you want to compare this outputs you must be sure that content of site does not change during page loading and so on. Also you need to take care of formatting like newlines between html tags and many other things